# Preserving symmetry and positive semi-definiteness during numerical integration.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, covariance

I want to numerically integrate the following differential equation of a covariance matrix $C$,

$$
\dot{C}(t) = J(t)^TC(t) + CJ(t) + \Sigma(t),
$$
with initial condition $C(0) = 0$. Here $\Sigma(t)$ is a covariance matrix as well, and $J$ is a Jacobian matrix. The matrices can be assumed to have a maximum dimension of 5$\times$5 for now, and even $\Sigma(t) = \Sigma$.

Are there any standard numerical methods for this problem? Since I'm only interested in the full covariance at the final time $T$, i.e. I only need to know $C(T)$, I thought about integrating only the upper triangular part of $C(t)$, and then at time $T$, multiply the upper triangular part and it's transpose to obtain $C(T)$. This will make the matrix symmetric, however, I'm not sure that it will preserve positive semi-definiteness.

Comment: Assume you can solve $\dot U(t) = J(t)U(t)$, $U(0)=I$,numerically, to some desired accuracy, then  $\frac{d}{dt}(U^TCU)=U^T\Sigma U$. The integration of the differential equation has been reduced to the quadrature of an integral.

Comment: This is interesting. Thank you! What kind of approach does this fall into?

Comment: This is standard in such equations, a textbook exercise. You could call it "applying an integrating factor".